# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' to 'bool'

Tags: c#, boolean

I am putting DiscordRPC in my application. I am making sure the Window is active so it can change easily and actually change the status. The issue is that when using ActiveForm, it does not work because it cannot convert it to a 'bool'. Here's my code.

```
private void active()
        {
            Form currentForm = Form.ActiveForm;

            if(Form.ActiveForm)
            {
                ptr2tools.Presence = new RichPresence()
                {
                    State = "Using pwf2tex",
                    Assets = new Assets()
                    {
                        LargeImageKey = "pwf2tex",
                        LargeImageText = "pwf2tex"
                    }
                };
                ptr2tools.DiscordClient.SetPresence(ptr2tools.Presence);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What are you trying to validate with if (Form.ActiveForm) ?

Comment: You might want to do if (Form.ActiveForm != null).

Answer (score 1):

Form.ActiveForm keeps the currently active form, or null if there is no active form.

```
 var currentForm = Form.ActiveForm;

 if(currentForm != null)
 {
     //logic
 }
```

Comment: This is working now, but the only issue is that it doesn't update with Discord. This is a different issue though, so thanks!

Comment: Great! Maybe because you are debugging, then you loose the activeForm focus. Try your logic without debugging or printing some message in a label

Answer (score 0):

In your code change:

```
if(Form.ActiveForm)
```

to

```
if (currentForm != null)
```

it should help you.
Note that `Form.ActiveForm` returns current active form or null, if there's no active form , so you can't test it in your `if` statement in that way. You can check if it's not null (and even make it without creating any object of Form):

```
if (Form.ActiveForm != null) //it do same
```